# API that provide hotel prices from various website?

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest

Iam currently working on website that provide list of hotel that available with the price from various website
but i can't find any API references that provide the data

i want to show price just like in a google maps like this

[image]

or  like this in a website called visitacity.com

[image]

Any references of an API that provide hotel prices from various website?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you'd like an API that gives you prices for hotels (multiple different).

This could be an option for you perhaps? (https://xotelo.com/) It is free as well. Note that I have not tried this before.

Here is a list for you to test/try if the link above is not sufficient - https://rapidapi.com/collection/hotels-apis